# Image loader is not working

Tags: android, android-activity, universal-image-loader

I am creating project same like this tutorial [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) previously it was working, but now the image is not showing me enabled storage permission also I am getting error like this

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
at com.example.admin.imageloading.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:143)`

line no 143 error

```
class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            try {
                Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

this is my code please some one help me

Comment: add some more code please and use picasso library insted of this old classes

Comment: Which IDE you used android studio or Eclipece??

Comment: @ArpitPatel refer androidhive if you want more code info i downloaded same code and executing. I am using android studio

Comment: first delete ImageLoader,FileCache,MemoryCache,Utils this class

Comment: Use glide or picasso for image loading. They offer caching resizing and transforming without any effort.

Comment: @ArpitPatel explain me details after i delete

Comment: then add this line in your gradle file compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

Comment: @GaneshP what you use for development eclipse or android studio??

Comment: @ArpitPatel i am using android studio. I don't want any 3rd party lib other then library i want some solution

Comment: bro just use this it's very easy and no need other code for that. Now goto the gradle file and add this line in depedencies  "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

Comment: @ArpitPatel i tried its working fine but our requirement is without any 3rd party lib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110458/discussion-between-arpit-patel-and-ganesh-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set image **without using any 3rd party libs** so try this

```
try { 
    URL newurl = new URL(image_url); 
    Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); 
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
} catch (IOException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

**OR**

use **picasso** library

add in your gradle file

```
dependencies {

   compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

}
```

Then add internet permission in android menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then add this below code in  **AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity**

```
  public class AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
            int loader = R.drawable.loader;

            // Imageview to show
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            // Image url
            String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

          //Loading image from below url into imageView

         Picasso.with(AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.this)
                .load(url)
                .into(image);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @ArpitPatel how to do image cache

Comment: give me link of your question

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
```

You are triying to get the activity's context from a view. Since `appcompat-v7:24.0.0` the context from images doesn't work like before, so now you can't do that.

You have two choices: Downgrade or find another way to pass the context to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Glide or Picasso for Image loading from URL.

For **Glide**, add

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Then:

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

 Glide.with(this).load("http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg").into(imageView);
```

or see the documentation for details. https://github.com/bumptech/glide .

For **Picasso**,  add Dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

After that Use this code to load image from URL:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView);
```

If you want to see details follow this: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I don't want any lib. i want simple code to cache and display image

Comment: It is lot easy to use these libraries than trying to write buggy codes. They are hugely used now a days. What you can do it just one line of code  is massive.

Comment: yes you right, but our requirement is no need to use any 3rd party lib